# MyBatis error when compile SpringBoot project using GraalVM

Tags: mybatis, graalvm, spring-mybatis, graalvm-native-image

Here I am facing the following problem with MyBatis when I compile the SpringBoot project using GraaVM, the build process finished successfully and generates the **.exe** file, but when I run the program it throws the exception, but in case I run the jar file with `java -jar` command, it works well as expected:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(MapperScannerConfigurer.java:363) ~[web.exe:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[web.exe:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565) ~[web.exe:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[web.exe:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[web.exe:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[web.exe:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[web.exe:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[web.exe:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[web.exe:3.0.6]
    at com.adil.bms.web.BmsApplication.main(BmsApplication.java:19) ~[web.exe:na]
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogException: Error creating logger for logger org.mybatis.spring.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:54) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:47) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.logging.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:32) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner.<clinit>(ClassPathMapperScanner.java:61) ~[na:na]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:52) ~[na:na]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

- GraalVM version: **graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.1**
- SpringBoot version: **3.0.6**
- MyBatis version: **3.5.13**

So, is there any extra configuration I am missing?
Thanks!!

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/1552) tracking GraalVM support. If there is a progress, the issue will be updated.